# JDBI MySQL using @BindList on MATCH() and AGAINST() fuction

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

When running `IN()` in a MySQL query, you're able to use `@BindList()` in JDBI to run your query towards a list.
However, I'd like to do the same with `MATCH()` and `REQUEST()`, however I'm not able to construct a query that seems to work for this.

This was my old query:

```
SELECT * FROM xxxxxxxxxxx WHERE request_id NOT IN (<blacklistedRequestIds>)
```

And what I want to do is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM bcsadmin_log WHERE MATCH(request_id) AGAINST(-<blacklistedRequestIds> IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(IN BOOLEAN MODE) is something that ChatGPT told me to use, I think it isn't important for the actual question though.

Could anyone give me some support?

Comment: Why do you want to use `MATCH() AGAINST()`? That is a much different type of search than `IN()` or `NOT IN()`. It would be useful only if your `request_id` column stores a paragraph of space-separated id values.

Comment: As I understand , it’s needed in order for MySQL FULLTEXT index to work. Maybe I’m underestimating MySQL, but I have 30GB of data and the column I want to search through is a TEXT type with around 150-300 letters and symbols.

Comment: `request_id` is a TEXT type?

Comment: Yeah I've accidently written the wrong column, it should be request_text which is a big string of texts, usually json formatted text.

Comment: Usually? Why not consistently? Then you could use a `JSON` column, and then you can use a [multi-valued index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued) to search it efficiently. Fulltext search is not the best solution for this.